# How to extract name and title from HTML?

Tags: regex

I'm looking to extract the first and last name in one group and the entire following line in the next group. I'm not sure how to incorporate line breaks into regex but I'm guessing it can be done. I've searched through the answers to similar questions and haven't found any that work. Can anyone help?

Here's the output I'm looking for:

Group 1: John Smith

Group 2: [Everything in the line below the name line]

Example text is here:
https://regex101.com/r/2vt0zw/1

Comment: add more description, what you want to acheive

Comment: Maybe you want something like [https://regex101.com/r/2vt0zw/2](https://regex101.com/r/2vt0zw/2). But this is definitely prone to error, you better find another way to filter your data.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please provide more information an examples of what you're asking. I just barely understood.

You can use this regex to achieve what you want:

```
^(\w*? \S*?)$\s^(.*)$
```

It works for names with two parts (can be adjusted however you need though)

You can see the updated example here:
https://regex101.com/r/2vt0zw/4